# Cannot run webpack watch in VScode command

Tags: webpack

Hi I am encountered a problem when I am trying to run a project locally. So after `npm install` I tried `npm run local` but I got `[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--watch'`. First I thought maybe my webpack version is too new but then I realize if I run `webpack --watch`, there is an error too. Below is the error I have.

```
 [webpack-cli] { Error: Cannot find module './configs/webpack.undefined.config.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at buildConfig (C:\Users\myname\filepath\webpack.config.js:2:12)
        at loadConfigByPath (C:\Users\myname\filepath\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1745:27)
        at process.runNextTicks [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/task_queues.js:52:5)        
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:871:11)
        at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

I have webpack-cli installed. If anyone knows what the problem is or need more information to detect the problem. I think my environment variables are okay. I have tried to delete the `node-module` files and `package_lock.json` file several times and reinstalled npm.